# Proguard: IllegalArgumentException: Stacks have different current sizes

Tags: android, proguard

Proguard is crashing with "Proguard returned with error code 1", and this crash in the console:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Stacks have different current sizes [0] and [1]
at proguard.evaluation.Stack.generalize(Stack.java:125)
at proguard.evaluation.TracedStack.generalize(TracedStack.java:140)
at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateSingleInstructionBlock(PartialEvaluator.java:683)
at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateInstructionBlock(PartialEvaluator.java:587)
at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.visitExceptionInfo(PartialEvaluator.java:1078)
at proguard.classfile.visitor.ExceptionHandlerFilter.visitExceptionInfo(ExceptionHandlerFilter.java:67)
at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.exceptionsAccept(CodeAttribute.java:186)
at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateExceptionHandlers(PartialEvaluator.java:1018)
at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateInstructionBlockAndExceptionHandlers(PartialEvaluator.java:567)
at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.visitCodeAttribute0(PartialEvaluator.java:264)
at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.visitCodeAttribute(PartialEvaluator.java:181)
at proguard.optimize.evaluation.LivenessAnalyzer.visitCodeAttribute(LivenessAnalyzer.java:205)
at proguard.optimize.evaluation.VariableOptimizer.visitCodeAttribute(VariableOptimizer.java:105)
at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.accept(CodeAttribute.java:101)
at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.attributesAccept(ProgramMethod.java:79)
at proguard.classfile.attribute.visitor.AllAttributeVisitor.visitProgramMember(AllAttributeVisitor.java:95)
at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitProgramMethod(SimplifiedVisitor.java:91)
at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.accept(ProgramMethod.java:71)
at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.methodsAccept(ProgramClass.java:504)
at proguard.classfile.visitor.AllMethodVisitor.visitProgramClass(AllMethodVisitor.java:47)
at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:346)
at proguard.classfile.ClassPool.classesAccept(ClassPool.java:116)
at proguard.optimize.Optimizer.execute(Optimizer.java:833)
at proguard.ProGuard.optimize(ProGuard.java:306)
at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:115)
at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

I have narrowed it down to a try catch block for an IOException.  If I comment out that try catch block then it shows this error for another IOException try catch block elsewhere in the app.  If I comment that one out, then it successfully builds.

So in both places proguard seems to be crashing on an IOException try catch block. These blocks have been in the code in previous builds that went through proguard without any trouble before.

Also, there are other IOException catch blocks that don't give any errors.

I tried this with proguard 4.5, 4.6, and 4.7 and all failed.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in ProGuard. You can log it on [ProGuard's bug tracker](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?atid=474704&group_id=54750&func=browse), preferably with a small test case that allows me to reproduce the problem, or you can [mail it](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/feedback.html) to me (Eric, developer of ProGuard).

For the time being, you can work around the problem by switching off optimization (with the option `-dontoptimize`).

Comment: first off, thanks so much for proguard, it is truly awesome and easy to use. I went ahead and filed a bug. For the sake of making this stack overflow post complete, here is the link https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3487940&group_id=54750&atid=474704  Thanks again.

Comment: it still happens with ProGuard version 5.2.1 :-(

Comment: 5.3.3 also. what is the solution here?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error for proguard 5.3.3 on xamarin forms project. my problem was i was having files missing in my proguard folder because when you download a version of proguard from their website, you dont have these txt files in the downloaded zip. It is always better to backup your old proguard and copy these files from there or you can just create manually I believe.

[image]